# Changing Style Module

Tags: css, joomla

I need to format the display module from the current state to the second state in the photo below is another image transfer.
The last line displays the image in a standard module, I need to display the image on the primary line.

pic 1 : [image: standard style]

pic 2 : [image: Style that I need]

module template code :

```
<?php // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>
<table border="0" width="100%">

<?php
if($list[1]->disposition=="h")
echo "<tr>";
$i=0;
foreach ($list as $item) :  
$order=explode("-",$item->ordering);
$cntorder=count($order);

if($i < $item->count_pic) { 

if($list[1]->disposition=="v"||!$list[1]->disposition)
print "<tr>";
?>
    <td valign="top" class="thumbsup-image latestnews<?php echo $item->css?>">
        <?php 
        if($item->front) {
            if($item->show_thumb) {
                if($item->link_thumb)
                echo "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$item->link."\">";

                echo $item->imgbig;

                if($item->link_thumb)
                echo "</a>";
            }

            for($j=0;$j<$cntorder;$j++){

            if($order[$j]=="t"&&$item->show_title) {
                if($item->link_title)
                echo "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"newsmod".$item->css."\">";

                echo "<H1>";
                echo "<li class=\"newsmod".$item->css."\">".$item->title."</li>";
                echo "</H1>";

                if($item->link_title)
                echo "</a>";
            }
            if($order[$j]=="i"&&$item->show_intro){

                if($item->link_intro)
                echo "<a href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"thumbsup-intro".$item->css."\">";

                echo $item->introtext;

                if($item->link_intro)
                echo "</a>";

                if($item->show_readmore){
                    echo "<a href=\"".$item->link."\">";
                    echo JText::_('more');
                    echo "</a>";
                }
            }
            if($order[$j]=="d"&&$item->show_date) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-date".$item->css."\">".JHTML::_('date', $item->created, $item->date_f)."</div>";
            }
            if($order[$j]=="a"&&$item->show_author) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-author".$item->css."\">";
                JText::printf('Written by',$item->author);
                echo "</div>";
            }
            if($order[$j]=="h"&&$item->show_hits) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-hits".$item->css."\">";
                JText::printf('Hits',$item->hits); 
                echo " ".$item->hits;
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }

        } else {
            if($item->show_thumb){

                if($item->link_thumb)
                echo "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"thumbsup-thumb".$item->css."\">";

                echo $item->imgsmall." ";

                if($item->link_thumb)
                echo "</a>";

            }

            if($item->imgcolumn)
            print "</ul><td valign=\"top\" class=\"latestnews".$item->css."\">";

        for($j=0;$j<$cntorder;$j++){

            if($order[$j]=="t"&&$item->show_title) {
                echo "<li class=\"newsmod".$item->css."\">";

                if($item->link_title)
                echo "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"newsmod".$item->css."\">";

                echo $item->title;

                if($item->link_title)
                echo "</a>";

                echo "</li>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="i"&&$item->show_intro){
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-intro".$item->css."\">";

                if($item->link_intro)
                echo "<a href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"thumbsup-intro".$item->css."\">";

                echo $item->introtext;

                if($item->link_intro)
                echo "</a>";

                if($item->show_readmore) {
                    echo "<a href=\"".$item->link."\">";
                    echo JText::_('more');
                    echo "</a>";
                }
                echo "</div>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="d"&&$item->show_date) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-date".$item->css."\">".JHTML::_('date', $item->created, $item->date_f)."</div>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="a"&&$item->show_author) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-author".$item->css."\">";
                JText::printf('Written by',$item->author);
                echo "</div>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="h"&&$item->show_hits) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-hits".$item->css."\">";
                JText::printf('Hits',$item->hits); 
                echo " ".$item->hits;
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
    }   ?>

    </ul>

<?php   if($list[1]->disposition=="v"||!$list[1]->disposition)
        print "</tr>";
?>

<?php  } else { 
    if($list[1]->disposition=="v"||!$list[1]->disposition)
    print "<tr>";
?>
    <ul valign="top" class="latestnews<?php echo $item->css?>">
        <?php 
        for($j=0;$j<$cntorder;$j++){

            if($order[$j]=="t"&&$item->show_title) {
                echo "<li class=\"newsmod".$item->css."\">";

                if($item->link_title)
                echo "<a target='_blank' href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"newsmod".$item->css."\">";

                if($item->front) echo "<H1>";
                echo $item->title;
                if($item->front) echo "</H1>";

                if($item->link_title)
                echo "</a>";

                echo "</li>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="i"&&$item->show_intro){
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-intro".$item->css."\">";

                if($item->link_intro)
                echo "<a href=\"".$item->link."\" class=\"thumbsup-intro".$item->css."\">";

                echo $item->introtext;

                if($item->link_intro)
                echo "</a>";

                if($item->show_readmore) echo JText::_('more');
                echo "</div>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="d"&&$item->show_date) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-date".$item->css."\">".JHTML::_('date', $item->created, $item->date_f)."</div>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="a"&&$item->show_author) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-author".$item->css."\">";
                JText::printf('Written by',$item->author);
                echo "</div>";
            }

            if($order[$j]=="h"&&$item->show_hits) {
                echo "<div class=\"thumbsup-hits".$item->css."\">";
                JText::printf('Hits',$item->hits); 
                echo " ".$item->hits;
                echo "</div>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if($list[1]->disposition=="v"||!$list[1]->disposition)
        print "</tr>";
    ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php $i++; endforeach; 

 if($list[1]->disposition=="h")
    print "</tr>";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything of yourself before posting this question? Also, might be easier if you post a link to your site, as it might just need some CSS tweaks

Comment: I've tested several different states, the problem is not solved, you can help?
Css does not solve the problem!